# How to git stash pop the last stash created on current branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-stash

I want to work with different branches and it would be useful for git to remember which stash is for which branch. So that when I `git stash pop` it only pops the stash that was created on current branch, if not - does nothing.

Basically whenever I switch branch I want to write `git stash pop` in case I had any work saved on this branch with `git stash -u`

It has to be a script or a one-liner to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is currently not supported by git.

But you can make a copy of the `git-stash` script and customize it a little bit. I would name the copy `git-bstash`(`b` for branch aware)

The `git-stash` script saves the stashes to the file `GIT_DIR/refs/stash`. If you  include the current branch in that path it will do what you want.

Change this line in the script

```
ref_stash=refs/stash
```

to e.g.

```
cur_ref=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
stash_path=refs/bstash/${cur_ref}
mkdir -p "${stash_path}"
ref_stash=${stash_path}/stash
```

Here is the complete script. Just put it in a folder that is in your `PATH` and use it like the normal stash command `git bstash` or `git bstash list`.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Copyright (c) 2007, Nanako Shiraishi

dashless=$(basename "$0" | sed -e 's/-/ /')
USAGE="list [<options>]
   or: $dashless show [<stash>]
   or: $dashless drop [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
   or: $dashless ( pop | apply ) [--index] [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
   or: $dashless branch <branchname> [<stash>]
   or: $dashless [save [--patch] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-q|--quiet]
               [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [<message>]]
   or: $dashless clear"

SUBDIRECTORY_OK=Yes
OPTIONS_SPEC=
START_DIR=$(pwd)
. git-sh-setup
. git-sh-i18n
require_work_tree
cd_to_toplevel

TMP="$GIT_DIR/.git-stash.$$"
TMPindex=${GIT_INDEX_FILE-"$(git rev-parse --git-path index)"}.stash.$$
trap 'rm -f "$TMP-"* "$TMPindex"' 0

cur_ref=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
stash_path=refs/bstash/${cur_ref}
mkdir -p "${stash_path}"
ref_stash=${stash_path}/stash

if git config --get-colorbool color.interactive; then
       help_color="$(git config --get-color color.interactive.help 'red bold')"
       reset_color="$(git config --get-color '' reset)"
else
       help_color=
       reset_color=
fi

no_changes () {
    git diff-index --quiet --cached HEAD --ignore-submodules -- &&
    git diff-files --quiet --ignore-submodules &&
    (test -z "$untracked" || test -z "$(untracked_files)")
}

untracked_files () {
    excl_opt=--exclude-standard
    test "$untracked" = "all" && excl_opt=
    git ls-files -o -z $excl_opt
}

clear_stash () {
    if test $# != 0
    then
        die "$(gettext "git stash clear with parameters is unimplemented")"
    fi
    if current=$(git rev-parse --verify --quiet $ref_stash)
    then
        git update-ref -d $ref_stash $current
    fi
}

create_stash () {
    stash_msg="$1"
    untracked="$2"

    git update-index -q --refresh
    if no_changes
    then
        exit 0
    fi

    # state of the base commit
    if b_commit=$(git rev-parse --verify HEAD)
    then
        head=$(git rev-list --oneline -n 1 HEAD --)
    else
        die "$(gettext "You do not have the initial commit yet")"
    fi

    if branch=$(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD)
    then
        branch=${branch#refs/heads/}
    else
        branch='(no branch)'
    fi
    msg=$(printf '%s: %s' "$branch" "$head")

    # state of the index
    i_tree=$(git write-tree) &&
    i_commit=$(printf 'index on %s\n' "$msg" |
        git commit-tree $i_tree -p $b_commit) ||
        die "$(gettext "Cannot save the current index state")"

    if test -n "$untracked"
    then
        # Untracked files are stored by themselves in a parentless commit, for
        # ease of unpacking later.
        u_commit=$(
            untracked_files | (
                GIT_INDEX_FILE="$TMPindex" &&
                export GIT_INDEX_FILE &&
                rm -f "$TMPindex" &&
                git update-index -z --add --remove --stdin &&
                u_tree=$(git write-tree) &&
                printf 'untracked files on %s\n' "$msg" | git commit-tree $u_tree  &&
                rm -f "$TMPindex"
        ) ) || die "Cannot save the untracked files"

        untracked_commit_option="-p $u_commit";
    else
        untracked_commit_option=
    fi

    if test -z "$patch_mode"
    then

        # state of the working tree
        w_tree=$( (
            git read-tree --index-output="$TMPindex" -m $i_tree &&
            GIT_INDEX_FILE="$TMPindex" &&
            export GIT_INDEX_FILE &&
            git diff --name-only -z HEAD -- >"$TMP-stagenames" &&
            git update-index -z --add --remove --stdin <"$TMP-stagenames" &&
            git write-tree &&
            rm -f "$TMPindex"
        ) ) ||
            die "$(gettext "Cannot save the current worktree state")"

    else

        rm -f "$TMP-index" &&
        GIT_INDEX_FILE="$TMP-index" git read-tree HEAD &&

        # find out what the user wants
        GIT_INDEX_FILE="$TMP-index" \
            git add--interactive --patch=stash -- &&

        # state of the working tree
        w_tree=$(GIT_INDEX_FILE="$TMP-index" git write-tree) ||
        die "$(gettext "Cannot save the current worktree state")"

        git diff-tree -p HEAD $w_tree -- >"$TMP-patch" &&
        test -s "$TMP-patch" ||
        die "$(gettext "No changes selected")"

        rm -f "$TMP-index" ||
        die "$(gettext "Cannot remove temporary index (can't happen)")"

    fi

    # create the stash
    if test -z "$stash_msg"
    then
        stash_msg=$(printf 'WIP on %s' "$msg")
    else
        stash_msg=$(printf 'On %s: %s' "$branch" "$stash_msg")
    fi
    w_commit=$(printf '%s\n' "$stash_msg" |
    git commit-tree $w_tree -p $b_commit -p $i_commit $untracked_commit_option) ||
    die "$(gettext "Cannot record working tree state")"
}

store_stash () {
    while test $# != 0
    do
        case "$1" in
        -m|--message)
            shift
            stash_msg="$1"
            ;;
        -q|--quiet)
            quiet=t
            ;;
        *)
            break
            ;;
        esac
        shift
    done
    test $# = 1 ||
    die "$(eval_gettext "\"$dashless store\" requires one <commit> argument")"

    w_commit="$1"
    if test -z "$stash_msg"
    then
        stash_msg="Created via \"git stash store\"."
    fi

    git update-ref --create-reflog -m "$stash_msg" $ref_stash $w_commit
    ret=$?
    test $ret != 0 && test -z $quiet &&
    die "$(eval_gettext "Cannot update \$ref_stash with \$w_commit")"
    return $ret
}

save_stash () {
    keep_index=
    patch_mode=
    untracked=
    while test $# != 0
    do
        case "$1" in
        -k|--keep-index)
            keep_index=t
            ;;
        --no-keep-index)
            keep_index=n
            ;;
        -p|--patch)
            patch_mode=t
            # only default to keep if we don't already have an override
            test -z "$keep_index" && keep_index=t
            ;;
        -q|--quiet)
            GIT_QUIET=t
            ;;
        -u|--include-untracked)
            untracked=untracked
            ;;
        -a|--all)
            untracked=all
            ;;
        --help)
            show_help
            ;;
        --)
            shift
            break
            ;;
        -*)
            option="$1"
            # TRANSLATORS: $option is an invalid option, like
            # `--blah-blah'. The 7 spaces at the beginning of the
            # second line correspond to "error: ". So you should line
            # up the second line with however many characters the
            # translation of "error: " takes in your language. E.g. in
            # English this is:
            #
            #    $ git stash save --blah-blah 2>&1 | head -n 2
            #    error: unknown option for 'stash save': --blah-blah
            #           To provide a message, use git stash save -- '--blah-blah'
            eval_gettextln "error: unknown option for 'stash save': \$option
       To provide a message, use git stash save -- '\$option'"
            usage
            ;;
        *)
            break
            ;;
        esac
        shift
    done

    if test -n "$patch_mode" && test -n "$untracked"
    then
        die "Can't use --patch and --include-untracked or --all at the same time"
    fi

    stash_msg="$*"

    git update-index -q --refresh
    if no_changes
    then
        say "$(gettext "No local changes to save")"
        exit 0
    fi
    git reflog exists $ref_stash ||
        clear_stash || die "$(gettext "Cannot initialize stash")"

    create_stash "$stash_msg" $untracked
    store_stash -m "$stash_msg" -q $w_commit ||
    die "$(gettext "Cannot save the current status")"
    say Saved working directory and index state "$stash_msg"

    if test -z "$patch_mode"
    then
        git reset --hard ${GIT_QUIET:+-q}
        test "$untracked" = "all" && CLEAN_X_OPTION=-x || CLEAN_X_OPTION=
        if test -n "$untracked"
        then
            git clean --force --quiet -d $CLEAN_X_OPTION
        fi

        if test "$keep_index" = "t" && test -n $i_tree
        then
            git read-tree --reset -u $i_tree
        fi
    else
        git apply -R < "$TMP-patch" ||
        die "$(gettext "Cannot remove worktree changes")"

        if test "$keep_index" != "t"
        then
            git reset
        fi
    fi
}

have_stash () {
    git rev-parse --verify --quiet $ref_stash >/dev/null
}

list_stash () {
    have_stash || return 0
    git log --format="%gd: %gs" -g --first-parent -m "$@" $ref_stash --
}

show_stash () {
    ALLOW_UNKNOWN_FLAGS=t
    assert_stash_like "$@"

    if test -z "$FLAGS"
    then
        if test "$(git config --bool stash.showStat || echo true)" = "true"
        then
            FLAGS=--stat
        fi

        if test "$(git config --bool stash.showPatch || echo false)" = "true"
        then
            FLAGS=${FLAGS}${FLAGS:+ }-p
        fi

        if test -z "$FLAGS"
        then
            return 0
        fi
    fi

    git diff ${FLAGS} $b_commit $w_commit
}

show_help () {
    exec git help stash
    exit 1
}

#
# Parses the remaining options looking for flags and
# at most one revision defaulting to ${ref_stash}@{0}
# if none found.
#
# Derives related tree and commit objects from the
# revision, if one is found.
#
# stash records the work tree, and is a merge between the
# base commit (first parent) and the index tree (second parent).
#
#   REV is set to the symbolic version of the specified stash-like commit
#   IS_STASH_LIKE is non-blank if ${REV} looks like a stash
#   IS_STASH_REF is non-blank if the ${REV} looks like a stash ref
#   s is set to the SHA1 of the stash commit
#   w_commit is set to the commit containing the working tree
#   b_commit is set to the base commit
#   i_commit is set to the commit containing the index tree
#   u_commit is set to the commit containing the untracked files tree
#   w_tree is set to the working tree
#   b_tree is set to the base tree
#   i_tree is set to the index tree
#   u_tree is set to the untracked files tree
#
#   GIT_QUIET is set to t if -q is specified
#   INDEX_OPTION is set to --index if --index is specified.
#   FLAGS is set to the remaining flags (if allowed)
#
# dies if:
#   * too many revisions specified
#   * no revision is specified and there is no stash stack
#   * a revision is specified which cannot be resolve to a SHA1
#   * a non-existent stash reference is specified
#   * unknown flags were set and ALLOW_UNKNOWN_FLAGS is not "t"
#

parse_flags_and_rev()
{
    test "$PARSE_CACHE" = "$*" && return 0 # optimisation
    PARSE_CACHE="$*"

    IS_STASH_LIKE=
    IS_STASH_REF=
    INDEX_OPTION=
    s=
    w_commit=
    b_commit=
    i_commit=
    u_commit=
    w_tree=
    b_tree=
    i_tree=
    u_tree=

    REV=$(git rev-parse --no-flags --symbolic --sq "$@") || exit 1

    FLAGS=
    for opt
    do
        case "$opt" in
            -q|--quiet)
                GIT_QUIET=-t
            ;;
            --index)
                INDEX_OPTION=--index
            ;;
            --help)
                show_help
            ;;
            -*)
                test "$ALLOW_UNKNOWN_FLAGS" = t ||
                    die "$(eval_gettext "unknown option: \$opt")"
                FLAGS="${FLAGS}${FLAGS:+ }$opt"
            ;;
        esac
    done

    eval set -- $REV

    case $# in
        0)
            have_stash || die "$(gettext "No stash found.")"
            set -- ${ref_stash}@{0}
        ;;
        1)
            :
        ;;
        *)
            die "$(eval_gettext "Too many revisions specified: \$REV")"
        ;;
    esac

    REV=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --verify --quiet "$1") || {
        reference="$1"
        die "$(eval_gettext "\$reference is not a valid reference")"
    }

    i_commit=$(git rev-parse --verify --quiet "$REV^2") &&
    set -- $(git rev-parse "$REV" "$REV^1" "$REV:" "$REV^1:" "$REV^2:" 2>/dev/null) &&
    s=$1 &&
    w_commit=$1 &&
    b_commit=$2 &&
    w_tree=$3 &&
    b_tree=$4 &&
    i_tree=$5 &&
    IS_STASH_LIKE=t &&
    test "$ref_stash" = "$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name "${REV%@*}")" &&
    IS_STASH_REF=t

    u_commit=$(git rev-parse --verify --quiet "$REV^3") &&
    u_tree=$(git rev-parse "$REV^3:" 2>/dev/null)
}

is_stash_like()
{
    parse_flags_and_rev "$@"
    test -n "$IS_STASH_LIKE"
}

assert_stash_like() {
    is_stash_like "$@" || {
        args="$*"
        die "$(eval_gettext "'\$args' is not a stash-like commit")"
    }
}

is_stash_ref() {
    is_stash_like "$@" && test -n "$IS_STASH_REF"
}

assert_stash_ref() {
    is_stash_ref "$@" || {
        args="$*"
        die "$(eval_gettext "'\$args' is not a stash reference")"
    }
}

apply_stash () {

    assert_stash_like "$@"

    git update-index -q --refresh || die "$(gettext "unable to refresh index")"

    # current index state
    c_tree=$(git write-tree) ||
        die "$(gettext "Cannot apply a stash in the middle of a merge")"

    unstashed_index_tree=
    if test -n "$INDEX_OPTION" && test "$b_tree" != "$i_tree" &&
            test "$c_tree" != "$i_tree"
    then
        git diff-tree --binary $s^2^..$s^2 | git apply --cached
        test $? -ne 0 &&
            die "$(gettext "Conflicts in index. Try without --index.")"
        unstashed_index_tree=$(git write-tree) ||
            die "$(gettext "Could not save index tree")"
        git reset
    fi

    if test -n "$u_tree"
    then
        GIT_INDEX_FILE="$TMPindex" git-read-tree "$u_tree" &&
        GIT_INDEX_FILE="$TMPindex" git checkout-index --all &&
        rm -f "$TMPindex" ||
        die 'Could not restore untracked files from stash'
    fi

    eval "
        GITHEAD_$w_tree='Stashed changes' &&
        GITHEAD_$c_tree='Updated upstream' &&
        GITHEAD_$b_tree='Version stash was based on' &&
        export GITHEAD_$w_tree GITHEAD_$c_tree GITHEAD_$b_tree
    "

    if test -n "$GIT_QUIET"
    then
        GIT_MERGE_VERBOSITY=0 && export GIT_MERGE_VERBOSITY
    fi
    if git merge-recursive $b_tree -- $c_tree $w_tree
    then
        # No conflict
        if test -n "$unstashed_index_tree"
        then
            git read-tree "$unstashed_index_tree"
        else
            a="$TMP-added" &&
            git diff-index --cached --name-only --diff-filter=A $c_tree >"$a" &&
            git read-tree --reset $c_tree &&
            git update-index --add --stdin <"$a" ||
                die "$(gettext "Cannot unstage modified files")"
            rm -f "$a"
        fi
        squelch=
        if test -n "$GIT_QUIET"
        then
            squelch='>/dev/null 2>&1'
        fi
        (cd "$START_DIR" && eval "git status $squelch") || :
    else
        # Merge conflict; keep the exit status from merge-recursive
        status=$?
        git rerere
        if test -n "$INDEX_OPTION"
        then
            gettextln "Index was not unstashed." >&2
        fi
        exit $status
    fi
}

pop_stash() {
    assert_stash_ref "$@"

    if apply_stash "$@"
    then
        drop_stash "$@"
    else
        status=$?
        say "The stash is kept in case you need it again."
        exit $status
    fi
}

drop_stash () {
    assert_stash_ref "$@"

    git reflog delete --updateref --rewrite "${REV}" &&
        say "$(eval_gettext "Dropped \${REV} (\$s)")" ||
        die "$(eval_gettext "\${REV}: Could not drop stash entry")"

    # clear_stash if we just dropped the last stash entry
    git rev-parse --verify --quiet "$ref_stash@{0}" >/dev/null ||
    clear_stash
}

apply_to_branch () {
    test -n "$1" || die "$(gettext "No branch name specified")"
    branch=$1
    shift 1

    set -- --index "$@"
    assert_stash_like "$@"

    git checkout -b $branch $REV^ &&
    apply_stash "$@" && {
        test -z "$IS_STASH_REF" || drop_stash "$@"
    }
}

PARSE_CACHE='--not-parsed'
# The default command is "save" if nothing but options are given
seen_non_option=
for opt
do
    case "$opt" in
    -*) ;;
    *) seen_non_option=t; break ;;
    esac
done

test -n "$seen_non_option" || set "save" "$@"

# Main command set
case "$1" in
list)
    shift
    list_stash "$@"
    ;;
show)
    shift
    show_stash "$@"
    ;;
save)
    shift
    save_stash "$@"
    ;;
apply)
    shift
    apply_stash "$@"
    ;;
clear)
    shift
    clear_stash "$@"
    ;;
create)
    shift
    create_stash "$*" && echo "$w_commit"
    ;;
store)
    shift
    store_stash "$@"
    ;;
drop)
    shift
    drop_stash "$@"
    ;;
pop)
    shift
    pop_stash "$@"
    ;;
branch)
    shift
    apply_to_branch "$@"
    ;;
*)
    case $# in
    0)
        save_stash &&
        say "$(gettext "(To restore them type \"git stash apply\")")"
        ;;
    *)
        usage
    esac
    ;;
esac
```

**EDIT**

I'm using git `version 2.7.0.windows.1` and all commands seem to work properly. I even tried it in detached `HEAD`. E.g.

```
git checkout --detach
HEAD is now at 17d6f21... ...

touch test
git add test

git bstash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on (no branch): 17d6f21 ....
HEAD is now at 17d6f21 ....

git bstash list
bstash/HEAD/stash@{0}: WIP on (no branch): 17d6f21 ...

git bstash show bstash/HEAD/stash@{0}
  test | 0
  1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

git bstash pop
HEAD detached at 17d6f21
Changes to be committed:
   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

          new file:   test234

Dropped refs/bstash/HEAD/stash@{0} (a118c012496b68e4245bbcba20a146870b5c356e)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I get `/usr/local/sbin/git-stash: 17: .: git-sh-setup: not found`, otherwise seems to be solving the right problem. The script is copyright 2007, seems it could be a bit outdated? ... mind sharing where it's from?

Comment: Can you still use the usual `git stash list` command to see all of the stashes created with the script?

Like @Arsenii Adriushchenko pointed out, it's writen out in plain text when you check the list of stashes, so maybe there could be a script that is a lot smaller to just pick that up?

Comment: @Aurimas I use `version 2.7.0.windows.1`. The script seems to be up to date. See https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-stash.sh. I just tried the commands `list`, `pop` and `show` and they worked.

Comment: thanks, I was using the script incorrectly, I was trying `git-stash.sh` inside terminal. Didn't read what you wrote very precisely, it looked impossible to expect an addition to git. Thanks. Working on Ubuntu 14.04 also.

Answer (score 5):

```
git stash 
git stash list

stash@{0}: WIP on **master**: 92ebc08 initial
stash@{1}: WIP on **t**: 0cc3db7 gfdgfd
```

Choose specific stash you want to pop

Example: `git stash pop stash@{1}`

Comment: Thanks, but it would be great to have a one liner or a script that picks this up for me.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @arseniyandru's example, you can parse the output `git stash list` to find which stash ref came from which branch. From the same starting point we see:

```
git stash 
git stash list

stash@{0}: WIP on **master**: 92ebc08 initial
stash@{1}: WIP on **t**: 0cc3db7 gfdgfd
```

We can write a simple bash function:

```
function get_stash_from_branch() {
  # First get the current branch. There are many ways to do this.
  BRANCH="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null)"
  
  # Then get the line containing the proper stash ref. You can use `tail -1`
  # instead, to get the oldest stash ref from this branch.
  STASH_LINE=$(git stash list | grep "${BRANCH}:" | head -1)

  # Parse out the ref name from the string we've called STASH_LINE.
  # Return via echo. When function is invoked within $() this value replaces it
  echo $STASH_LINE | awk '{print $1}' | tr -d ':'
}
```

And to use it:

`git stash pop $(get_stash_from_branch)`. You could also add a git alias in your gitconfig file with this oneliner:

```
popbranch = !"git stash pop $(echo $(git stash list | grep $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null) | head -1) | awk '{print $1}' | tr -d ':')"
```

Comment: Only issue is... you had better not name your branch as shas of other commits, or add tags to your stashes that are actually other branch names! These fagilities could be easily fixed with a better parser. That is, you will want to `grep` with a better pattern, and use a robust `sed` regex to parse out the stash ref instead of the incredibly simple use of `awk` + `tr`.

Comment: Also... if there are no stashes on this branch, then the function will return empty. This is bad, as it invokes `git stash pop` with no additional arguments. Well, you know what that does. One would need to either use this alias carefully or add proper error checking.